# Error occured while calling web service

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android web service calls. I am trying to develop an application that displays current temperature by making SOAP Web service call. When I try to run the application, I got the following error in the Logcat.

```
09-03 02:38:16.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 02:38:16.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1539): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
09-03 02:38:16.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):     at com.example.updatesnew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZip";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetCityWeatherByZip";
    private static final String NAMESPACE ="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/";
    private static final String URL = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP";
    TextView tv;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView01);
           SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = null;
//Here I am getting error. 
           SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME); 

           Request.addProperty("Texas","75011");
           soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
           soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
           soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        AndroidHttpTransport aht=new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
           try
           {
                aht.call(SOAP_ACTION,soapEnvelope);
                SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
                tv.setText("Status: "+resultString);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
```

I also have a doubt, whether `Request.addProperty("Texas","75011");` is the right way or not, for getting the current temperature of Texas City with ZIP code 75011. Please guide me, with a sample code if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use `threads` or `asynctask` for network related operations

Comment: @Raghunandan, how to use threads and asynctask? any example please?

Comment: search on stackoverflow you will find many similar posts. also did you add the ksoap jar to your libs folder?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Raghunandan, I have all the .jar files required. Now, when I started running my application, I got the error                                                                    09-03 03:12:22.466: E/dalvikvm(1632): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.example.updatesnew.MainActivity$SoapAccessTask.doInBackground

Comment: You do have jars but have you configured them correctly?

Comment: Thanks @Siddhesh, what do you mean by configuring them?

Comment: check your build path

Comment: @Siddhesh, build path is also configured correctly. I have cleaned the project, restarted eclipse. But also I am getting the same problem.

Comment: go to build path then in libraries tab; if you see any jar there remove it and in order and export tick everything except google apis then check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to do some operations with a web service in Android, you have to use AsyncTask to prevent the network on main thread error, here's a sample code I used when uploading something:

```
public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // do stuff before posting data
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            // 1 = post text data, 2 = post file
            int actionChoice = 2;

            // post a text data
            if(actionChoice==1){
                postText();
            }

            // post a file
            else{
                postFile();
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
        // do stuff after posting data
    }

// this will post our text data
private void postText(){
    try{
        // url where the data will be posted
        String postReceiverUrl = "http://yourdomain.com/post_data_receiver.php";
        Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

        // HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        // add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", "Mike"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", "Dalisay"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "mike@testmail.com"));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {

            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);

            // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

How the AsyncTask was used:

```
new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
```

[Here's a reference for you.](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/android-http-client.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Emkey, should I use the function call -     new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();                              inside onCreate() method, after calling setcontentView()?

Comment: @nki: Yes you are correct. or in any method where you need it.

Comment: I did what you have said. But also getting the same error.          09-03 05:08:22.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 09-03 05:08:22.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-03 05:08:22.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-03 05:08:22.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
at com.example.updatesnew.MainActivity$SoapAccessTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48)